# How can I call req.flash() from inside the mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, connect-flash

I have a problem calling req.flash inside mongoose function. I have tried lit everything. In one part of my code it works but in other it doesn't.

My code:

```
 router.post('/chngpwd', function(req, res, next) {
   var {currentpassword, newpassword, confirmnewpassword} = req.body;
   var uid = req.session.passport.user;
   if (newpassword == confirmnewpassword) {
     User.findById(uid).then(dbres => {
     req.flash('error_msg',"THIS MESSAGE DON'T WORK");  //DONT WORK
     });
   }else {
     req.flash('error_msg',"New passwords don't match"); //WORKS
   }
   res.redirect('/adminpanel/1');
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? What is the expected behaviour and what is happening?

Comment: I am not getting any error and nothing changes. Even if i console log req.session there is nothing stored in flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting it to /adminpanel/1 without waiting the response from the findById (async) function.
This should work:

```
router.post('/chngpwd', function(req, res, next) {
   var {currentpassword, newpassword, confirmnewpassword} = req.body;
   var uid = req.session.passport.user;
   if (newpassword == confirmnewpassword) {
     User.findById(uid).then(dbres => {
         req.flash('error_msg',"THIS MESSAGE DON'T WORK");
         res.redirect('/adminpanel/1');
     });
   }else {
     req.flash('error_msg',"New passwords don't match");
     res.redirect('/adminpanel/1');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I am just wondering if i can redirect with all flash messages at once. Is it possible ?

Comment: @kogik maybe you can do that using async/await syntax to await for `User.findById(uid)` call to complete.

Comment: @GCSDC Thank you a lot. Now it works a lot better with async.